# raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='\\\.vn', port=443)

Tags: python, replit

The problem I am facing is similar to the picture below. Both `pythonanywhere` and `replit` have this error, we can only use the sites on their whitelist and can't use other external sites, So is there any way to fix this problem?

Error message: [image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
  File "/home/runner/updateScore/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/updateScore/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/updateScore/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/updateScore/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/updateScore/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='\\\.vn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

I've searched all over the net and tried everything but nothing can fix it...

Comment: the site appears to be down, can you reach it with a browser?

Comment: It is possible that you cannot access the website of Vietnam...

https://i.imgur.com/AMD4LWY.png

Comment: what is that editor in the first image? if its an online editor then it might not be able to access Vietnam either

Comment: I tried using proxy in replit and got blocked xD, any other way or by pythonanywhere? But using proxy with pythonanywhere still get same result as above https://i.imgur.com/2Dc5zhB.png

Comment: i dont know about proxies, but you could use ToR, python has a library for interacting with tor called [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) which would let you pick vietnam as an exit (if one is available)